# Switch at the back of a battery eliminator

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, mechanical-failure

I have this variable voltage battery eliminator and the "switch" to hold the wire in place is broken. Is there any specific name for this "switch" and can I buy it somewhere to replace it or can you suggest some other way to overcome this please.

[image: Back of the battery eliminator]

[image: The broken part along with it's spring]

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult to be certain, but I suspect what you have is commonly known as a spring speaker clip. Using those terms in your search engine to find one that has listing for maximum and voltage. My search, done in the US, resulted in primarily US sources, [one of which](http://www.techtoolsupply.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=IC107BSSBK) lists a set that can handle 300 volts and 15 amps.

[image: speaker spring clip]

Answer (score -1):

If you don’t need it to stay original, then you could use screw- block connectors aka chocolate block connectors of a sufficient size for the wires necessary & current necessary.